# Vue JS Redirect url

Tags: javascript, vue.js, redirect, twitter, vue-router

I'm currently using hash mode in the VUE router and it is working fine. But I'm using Twitter in my project and there I want to define a callback-URL which is something like this `https://{BASE_URL}/#/confirm?auth=qwertyui`. Now Twitter is not accepting this URL as a callback because of the hash in between. I was thinking if there is a way to add a callback URL in Twitter with hash in it. Can anyone suggest some solutions to this. Thanks

This is my route to the component:

```
{
  path: '/confirm',
  name: 'confirmation',
  component: () => import('----componnet----')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set your Router mode to history the hashbang disappears I guess

```
new VueRouter({
    // ...
    mode: 'history'
})
```

Comment: I don't want to change the mode, because there will be a lot of changes to do that. I just want to redirect a particular route to my route. Is there any way that I can specify a full route in vue router and add a redirection to it.
For eg https://{BASE_URL}/confirmation. to https://{BASE_URL}/#/confirmation